# How to pass an array of conditions to a select query class?

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, class

I am trying to build a class to select records from table defined on user input.

my plan is to make a class that read user **input conditions as an array**, because there is a lot of other forms for other tables with different number of conditions. therefore I want to make one class that works with all.

basically am trying to achieve this statement:

```
select * from table_name where condition1=value1 AND condition2=value2
```

where the number of conditions varies depends on user input.

---

what I have done is this **class**:

```
class SelectQuery {

private $Error;
public $conn;
public $table;

public function __construct($conn){ //establish connection

        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

public function SelectData($table,$cols,array $conds){ 

    $this->table = $table;

    if($cols)
    {
       if($conds)
        {
        $i=0; $cond=''; 
        foreach ($conds as $key => $value){

            if($i==0)
            {
            $cond .= $key. '=' .$value;
             }
             else
             {
            $cond .= ' AND ' .$key. '=' .$value;
              }
            $i++;
             }


        $sql = 'SELECT '.$cols.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$cond.'';
        $stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stmt);

        $rows = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $data, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN);

        if($rows)
        {
           return $rows['0']['0'];
        }
        else
        {
        return NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT {$cols} FROM {$table}';
        $stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stmt);

        $rows = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $data, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN);

        if($rows)
        {
        return $rows['0']['0'];
        }
        else
        {
        return NULL;
        }
    }   

  }

}
```

and this is how the data is **sent** from **form**:

```
$manager = new OracleConnectManager();
$conn = $manager->establishConnection(); //establish connection

if( $conn ){

    $table = 'MAIN';
    $cols= '*';

    $conds = array(
    'id_number' => $_POST['id_number'],
    'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
    'secondname' => $_POST['secondname'],
    'thirdname' => $_POST['thirdname'],
    'familyname' => $_POST['familyname'],
    'department' => $_POST['department'],

        );

$sel = new SelectQuery($conn);
$dth = $sel->SelectData($table,$cols,$conds);
echo $dth;

}
```

when I run the code i get this **error**:

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00936: missing expression
```

(in the `SelectQuery` class, line: `oci_execute($stmt)`; )

```
Warning: oci_fetch_all(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch
```

(in the `SelectQuery` class, line: `$rows = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $data, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN);` )

and there is no *output*.

any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Easy way is print your `$sql` and take out the query actually formed. Usually a simple error!

Comment: you are right! I dont know why i did not think of that XD.. the statement looks like this:
SELECT * FROM main WHERE id_number=123456 AND name=value1 AND second=value2 AND family=value3

Comment: so i guess whats wrong is the quotes around values.. 'value1' instead of value1

Comment: But I guess ,that would lead to _INVALID Identifier_ error not _MISSING Expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things:

1. You need to validate all the `$_POST` values and build `$conds` array for values that are set in `$_POST`.
   Update:
   i.e. if you have only one or two post values then the $conds array should be:

   $conds = array(
     'id_number' => $_POST['id_number'],
     'firstname' => $_POST['firstname']
   )
2. In your foreach loop, `$value` needs to be quoted if it is varchar type as:

   ```
   foreach ($conds as $key => $value){

       if($i==0)
       {
       $cond .= "$key='$value'";
        }
        else
        {
       $cond .= " AND $key='$value'";
         }
       $i++;
   }
   ```

Update:
if you have int and varchar fields then do formatting when building array itself:

```
$conds = array(
  'id_number' => $_POST['id_number'],             // int type
  'firstname' => "'".$_POST['firstname']."'"      // string type
)
```

Comment: if i got you right, i need to make sure that the array contains filled $_POST variables? for example if the user fill id number only then the array should only contain the id number, not the other posts?

Comment: and what if the value is not varchar? what if it was number?

Comment: It works as you mentioned at the first time, it works for varchar too. the updated answer did not work. thanks @Sandeep Kumar for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
  else
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT ' . $cols . ' FROM ' . $table; 
        // Other Statements
    }
```

Hope the `ELSE` part for `$sql` should be framed like above?

Comment: yes it will be done like that, thanks for reminding me